# org-download-screenshot from pdf-tools with renaming according to pdf name and pdf page

Tags: org-mode, pdf-tools

I would like to use [org-download-screenshot](https://github.com/abo-abo/org-download/blob/master/org-download.el) (or some other function) in combination with pdf-tools.

This works quite well out of the box. What I am missing is a enhanced renaming of the screenshot.
That means, the png file should should be placed in the subdirectory ./img and be renamed according the name of the pdf file (e.g. first 10 characters) and the page of the pdf.

An alternative which I am using is on macos is this function

```
(defun screenShot_org()
  (interactive)
  (if buffer-file-name
      (progn
        (message "Waiting for region selection with mouse...")
        (let ((filename
               (concat 
                (read-file-name "Enter PNG Name:")
                "_"
                (format-time-string "%Y%m%d_%H%M%S") ".png")))
          (call-process "screencapture" nil nil nil "-s" filename)
          (insert (concat "
#+NAME: 
#+ATTR_ORG: :width 200
#+ATTR_LATEX: :width 0.9\\linewidth
[[file:img/" (file-name-nondirectory filename)"]]"))
                    )
        (message "File created and linked...")
        )
    (message "You're in a not saved buffer! Save it first!")
    )
  )
```

This basically asks for the file path and first part of the name, but does not recognize the pdf file name nor the pdf page number.

I hope it is clear, what I want to achieve...